# Docker containers in the same network cannot communicate with container names (M1 Mac)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run express, Prisma ORM, and postgre applications in Docker.

I have two containers in the same network, but they cannot communicate with each other unless they use the actual IP address instead of the container name. Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```html
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    container_name: urefer-backend
    networks:
      - backend
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/app/
      - /usr/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on: 
      - db
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://postgres:docker@urefer-db:5432/urefer?schema=public
    stdin_open: true # docker run -i
    tty: true        # docker run -t
  db:
    networks:
      - backend
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-postgres}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-docker}
      POSTGRES_DB: "urefer"
    container_name: urefer-db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
     - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
volumes:
  database-data:
networks:
  backend:
```

The urefer-backend container and the urefer-db container are in the same "backend" network. However, when I run `docker-compose up --build`, I always have a connection issue:

```html
urefer-backend | Error: Error in migration engine: Can't reach database server at `urefer-db`:`5432`
urefer-backend | 
urefer-backend | Please make sure your database server is running at `urefer-db`:`5432`.
```

When I replace "urefer-db" with the actual IP address of the db server, then it connects successfully. This I think means that there is something wrong with the DNS setup.

Could anyone please help me connect the two containers without using the actual IP address? the IP address for DB is always changing whenever I stop and restart the container, so it is really bothering to use.

#edit:
I got a suggestion from a comment to put all log and errors I got on the console.

```html
urefer-db | 
urefer-db | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
urefer-db | 
urefer-db | 2021-10-01 14:44:57.165 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.0 (Debian 14.0-1.pgdg110+1) on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
urefer-db | 2021-10-01 14:44:57.165 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
urefer-db | 2021-10-01 14:44:57.165 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
urefer-db | 2021-10-01 14:44:57.168 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
urefer-db | 2021-10-01 14:44:57.171 UTC [28] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-10-01 14:44:49 UTC
urefer-db | 2021-10-01 14:44:57.177 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
urefer-backend | Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
urefer-backend | Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "urefer", schema "public" at "urefer-db:5432"
urefer-backend | 
urefer-backend | Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `urefer-db`:`5432`
urefer-backend | 
urefer-backend | Please make sure your database server is running at `urefer-db`:`5432`.
urefer-backend | Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
urefer-backend |
```

When the backend service is up, it runs the command `npx prisma migrate dev --name init`, and this command creates this connection error.

Comment: If you look at the complete Compose logs, is the database container fully up and running by the time the application tries to connect to it, or are there more database startup logs after this error message?  Is there a little more detail in the error you quote, possibly an error message like "could not resolve name" or "connection refused"?  (The Compose file seems fine to me, if it specifies a couple of unnecessary options.)

Comment: @David Maze

I updated my post.

Comment: This seems to be associated with the following issue on the prisma github: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/12598

Answer (score -1):

You should use host name instead of container name. Containers uses hostname when communicate each other. So if you add hostname docker-compose for container it will work

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    container_name: urefer-backend
    networks:
      - backend
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/app/
      - /usr/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on: 
      - db
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://postgres:docker@urefer-db:5432/urefer?schema=public
    stdin_open: true # docker run -i
    tty: true        # docker run -t
  db:
    networks:
      - backend
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-postgres}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-docker}
      POSTGRES_DB: "urefer"
    container_name: urefer-db
    hostname: urefer-db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
     - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
volumes:
  database-data:
networks:
  backend:
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it, and I got the same error though: urefer-backend | Error: Error in migration engine: Can't reach database server at `urefer-db`:`5432`
urefer-backend | 
urefer-backend | Please make sure your database server is running at `urefer-db`:`5432`.

Comment: Is there a problem with the syntax of DATABASE_URL ? Did you try without port number ?

Comment: `hostname:` only changes how a container sees itself; in most cases the only practical effect you'll see from setting `hostname:` is a different name appearing in an interactive shell prompt.  It's not used for cross-container calls or anything else network-related.